# RxJS from() operator never completes

Tags: angular, sharepoint, rxjs

I'm trying to perform metadata update in the sharepoint list. In the component I have:

```
this.datasetService.updateMetadata(oldDatasetName, projectMetadata).subscribe(() => {
   this.onCompleted('DownloadDataset.Updated');
}, error => this.onError(error, 'DownloadDataset.UpdateError'));
```

Then in the service:

```
updateMetadata(oldDatasetName: string, metadata: ProjectDatasetModel): Observable<boolean[]> {
    const filterString = `DataSetName eq '${oldDatasetName}'`;
    return this.graphService.getFilteredListItems(ResourceNames.PROJECT_DATASET_LIST_NAME, filterString).pipe(switchMap(items => from(items).pipe(mergeMap(item => {
        const updated = { ...item, DataSetName: metadata.datasetName, DataSetDescription: metadata.datasetDescription };
        return this.graphService.updateListItem(ResourceNames.PROJECT_DATASET_LIST_NAME, updated.Id, updated);
    }), toArray(), tap(() => console.log("Update completed")))));
}
```

GraphService:

```
public getFilteredListItems(listTitle: string, filter: string): Observable<any[]> {
    const sub$ = new Subject<any[]>();
    this.configureSharepointToken().subscribe(configured => {
        sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.filter(filter).get().then((items: any[]) => {
            sub$.next(items);
        });
    });
    return sub$.asObservable();
}

public updateListItem(listTitle: string, itemId: number, listItem: any): Observable<boolean> {
    const sub$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    this.configureSharepointToken().subscribe(configured => {
        sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.getById(itemId).update(listItem)
            .then(iar => {
                sub$.next(true);
            });
    });

    return sub$.asObservable();
}
```

My issue is that if there are items to be updated, update does happen and I can the new metadata, but tap() never happens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **getFilteredListItems** and **updateListItem** you're return a subject that never completes.  The **toArray** operator won't execute until the subjects are closed.

The whole business of creating subjects and returning them is superfluous.  If **configureSharepointToken** returns an observable, then just **switchMap** from those streams to a new source.  Super fun fact:  Any operator that accepts observables will work on promises.  That is why the result of the **get** method can be passed into **switchMap**.

```
public getFilteredListItems(listTitle: string, filter: string): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.configureSharepointToken().pipe(
    switchMap(() =>  sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.filter(filter).get())
  );
}

public updateListItem(listTitle: string, itemId: number, listItem: any): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.configureSharepointToken().pipe(
    switchMap(() => sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.getById(itemId).update(listItem)),
    mapTo(true)
  );
}
```

One note, the **first** operator might need to be added at the beginning of the pipes in case **configureSharePointToken** stays open.  Personally it seems strange that it'll have more than one emission.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, your super fun fact is really super fun, it makes life a lot easier!